# Filebeat not supported in Solaris. How to collect logs?

Tags: logstash, solaris, elastic-stack, filebeat

Our Sever is hosted in Solaris(OS) but we are not able to install Filebeat to forward the logs to desired port as Filebeat is not supported in Solaris. Can someone here suggest any way to solve this problem. Please note we are told not to install Logstash in the server hosted machine.

Your advices are highly anticipated . Please do the needful.

Answer (score 2):

Filebeat can easily be compiled to run on Solaris 11/amd64, but that is not an officially supported platform based on [Elastic's support matrix](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix). All of the Filebeat project's tests pass on Solaris.

It may be be possible to compile Filebeat for Solaris/sparc using gccgo. Filebeat is written in Go, and the Go compiler supports Solaris/amd64 but not sparc which is why the gccgo compiler would be needed for sparc.

There is a filebeat-solaris-amd64 binary generated by Elastic's [Jenkins server](http://build-eu-00.elastic.co/view/Beats/job/Filebeat/) and published to [S3](https://beats-nightlies.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=jenkins/filebeat/) if you want to do a quick test, but otherwise I would recommend compiling it yourself from a release tag if you are going to be using it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options:

**Syslog**: Solaris systems typically come with syslog functionality built-in. You can configure syslog to send logs to a central syslog server. This central server can then aggregate logs from all your Solaris systems.

**rsyslog**: Similar to syslog, rsyslog is another logging daemon that can be configured to collect and forward logs to a central server. It's often more feature-rich and configurable than the default syslog daemon.
**Manual log collection**: In situations where automated log collection is not feasible, you may resort to manually collecting logs from each Solaris system and transferring them to a central location using secure file transfer methods like SCP or SFTP.