# Running FileBeat on Solaris

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have been trying to run FileBeat on Solaris - SunOS. I was successfully able to run logstash and elasticsearch on it. However, since FileBeat provides a executable to run instead of shell script, is creating the problem.

Can any of you please help on how to proceed with this.

Comment: You should mention the architecture (amd64 vs sparc) you are using. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37419289/503798). I use Filebeat on Solaris on amd64.

Comment: Hi AJ, the architecture is Sparcv9 sparc

Comment: Check answer on the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415473/filebeat-not-supported-in-solaris-how-to-collect-logs

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't run filebeat on Solaris:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/build-failure-docker-compose-not-found-on-solaris/47346/2

> We do not support Solaris as it has no go compiler.