# Can I use golang on Solaris 5.10?

Tags: go, solaris, filebeat

I'm trying to use `golang` on `Solaris 5.10 i86c (x86 + x86_64)` but I can't find a package made for `Solaris`.

In addition, I want this to make a binary file for `Filebeat` which runs in `Solaris 5.10` systems. The actual release of `Filebeat (amd64)` doesn't work on my `Solaris` distro.

Anyone can guide me a little bit?

Comment: IIRC, Go requires Illumos or Solaris 11 and above.

Answer (score 3):

Go supports Solaris 11 on amd64, but not sparc. To build for sparc you need to use gccgo.

To build a pure Go project for Solaris/amd64 you can use:

```
$ GOOS=solaris GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37419289/503798 for more info about Filebeat on Solaris (it includes a link to a Filebeat binary for solaris 11 on amd64).

Comment: For an official source that Go only supports AMD64-based Solaris 11 and later (at least as of time of writing): https://go.dev/doc/go1.3#solaris (I know this is a link to a really old Go version, but to my understanding, at the time of writing this comment, no new Go version has expanded official Go support to older Solaris versions or to non-AMD64 Solaris).