# Is there a command line tool to connect Azure SQL MI on Solaris11

Tags: unix, jdbc, odbc, solaris, azure-sql-managed-instance

1. According to Microsoft document, there is a sqlcmd utility which can be used on Windows server/system that can execute sql statement and bcp operation in command-line.
   Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16
2. There also a guide to install the SQL Server command-line tools sqlcmd and bcp on Linux.
   Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=redhat-install%2Credhat-offline

However, I am maintaining a Unix (Solaris11) server which want to execute sql statement and bcp operation in shell script that connect to Azure SQL Managed Instance. I cannot find out any Microsoft document to SQL Server command-line tools on Unix.

How can I install a command-line tools that can connect to Azure SQL MI and then execute sql statement and bcp operation within a shell script, to finish some business requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLCMD](https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd) is one of the SQL Server command line tools that Microsoft is making open source and built on GO language to make it portable. SQLCMD can be used to connect to Azure SQL and Azure SQL Managed instance and execute queries and SQL scripts. Based on [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000525/can-i-use-golang-on-solaris-5-10) Go supports Solaris 11 on amd64 architecture but not on SPARC. However, [here](https://gist.github.com/jxsl13/22f0d461e6e8b18a14869ddb46066523) I found a very promising article on porting GO to Sparc Solaris as well.

Comment: *porting GO to Sparc Solaris* The nice thing about Solaris is that code that compiles on x86 Solaris will almost certainly compile on SPARC, unless it uses really architecture-specific code such as embedded ASM statements.  The tough part is actually getting the code debugged and running, as x86 devs tend to be very lax with alignment and litter their code with misaligned accesses and other undefined behavior that almost always works on x86, but bad code like that **WILL** fail on SPARC systems.  If you're not worried about performance, though, the Oracle compiler's `-xmemalign` arg is useful.